# How to visualize two small samples with different sizes?

Tags: visualization

As part of a psychology experiment, I surveyed 15 users. I separated them in two groups, those who have become smoke free, and those who are still smoking. These groups have different sizes (9 and 6).

I want to show graphically that the smoke free group reported higher values of the survey index. This is my current best attempt, with Google Sheets:

[image]

However, I think that a correct comparison should have the same number of data points. I guess I need some form of interpolation, but not sure how to proceed.

An alternative approach is using a bubble chart:
[image]

My questions:
1. Would you recommend a different chart?
2. Should I have the same number of data points? If yes, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

By downloading the [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) you may use [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/).  If you are using Python then use the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) to access the engine in Python.

You may use [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) with [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to show the distribution of responses and label how may responses in each set.

I'll generate some responses for each of the two groups.

```
SeedRandom[123]
survey = MapThread[RandomVariate, {UniformDistribution /@ {{3, 5}, {2.5, 4}}, {6, 9}}]
```

> ```
> {{3.91144, 4.95565, 4.88643, 4.92443, 3.6047, 3.93342}, 
>  {2.59246, 3.07847, 3.14476, 3.66812, 2.57289, 3.4424, 2.91698, 2.63533, 3.81488}}
> ```

Then plot with a number of observations label located at the `"UpperFence"` of each set.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[
 Labeled[#, "Obs: " <> ToString@Length@#, "UpperFence"] & /@ survey,
 ChartLabels -> {"Smoke free", "Smoking"},
 ChartStyle -> {Orange, Purple},
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot

Comment: how to do it in google spreadsheet https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9146870

Comment: Thank you guys, this looks like a good solution. I had to scratch my head to figure out how to organize the data for Google Candlestick to work. I will wait a week before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

How's a net? Where you colourize binary (e.g. orange = smoker, blue = none-smoker) and the distance to the midpoint of the circle shows how happy they are.

Find also a screenshot how to arrange the data (i.e. Excel)

[image: Chart Idea]
[image: Aranged_data]

Comment: Thank you! This would not solve my problem because it does not provide a direct comparison of the two groups. The difference between the two samples is small, about 10%.